# Wakeup sleeping thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix, sleep

I'm using the nanosleep function in a multithreaded program. I'm having nanosleep act as a timer that should be able to be interrupted by another thread if a certain condition passes. I found on a website someone ask a similar question, and they said you can't wakeup from a sleep:
http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-431651.html

Is this true, or is it just with WinAPI (I'm programming in a UNIX environment)?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do this, why not just use a timed wait on a condvar?